# What is the name of this eslint rule: Replace `⏎········ with `?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

Error:

```
https://google.com/#q=prettier%2Fprettier  Replace `⏎················<router-view></router-view>⏎···········` with `·<router-view></router-view>`
[1]   src/assets/views/layouts/App.vue:6:32
```

The error shows when my Vue HTML code is formatted like this:

```
<v-container fluid>
    <router-view></router-view>
</v-container>
```

When the code is formatted like this, it passes the rule:

```
<v-container fluid> <router-view></router-view> </v-container>
```

The editor (VSCode) doesn't show the name of the error. I want to disable this rule but can't.

Comment: I think it could be very helpful to include some of the information that's asked at https://github.com/prettier/eslint-plugin-prettier/issues/new! (Alternatively, maybe you'll get better support by creating a GitHub issue on that project if you're using `eslint-plugin-prettier`?)

Comment: @therobinkim It is not an issue thus I do not think github issues are place for this kind of questions.